# upload file from AS3 to server via PHP

Tags: php, actionscript-3

In my website when a user login, PHP get his user name and store it in $_SESSION['myusername'].
I have a flash AS3 app in this site that user send(POST) some text and upload a few sound files in mp3 format in a few different steps. When he send text I do this with it:

```
<?php 
session_start();
$username =$_SESSION['myusername'];
mkdir('./uploads/'.$username,0666); 
$path = './uploads/'.$userna/'.$username.'.txt';        
$data = $_POST['writing']; 
file_put_contents($path,$data);
?>
```

It works properly. It creates a folder in uploads directory with a same name as his user name and create text file. I'm trying to do something like this for uploaded sound files. I want to create a folder for each user same as his username and then upload the files there:

```
<?php
session_start();
$username =$_SESSION['myusername'];

if($_FILES['Filedata']['size'] < 1500000){
 mkdir('./soundupload/'.$username,0666);
$uploads_dir = './soundupload/'.$username.'/';
if( $_FILES['Filedata']['error'] == 0 ){
    if( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'], $uploads_dir
    .$_FILES['Filedata']['name']) ){
        echo 'ok';
        exit();
    }
}
echo 'error';
exit();
```

But it doesn't work at all. Is it possible to do this? How I can do it?
    }else echo 'My error'; exit();
    ?>

**Update:**

```
 $username =$_POST['sesname'];

 mkdir('./soundupload/'.$username,0666);

 if($_FILES['Filedata']['size'] < 1500000){
 if( $_FILES['Filedata']['error'] == 0 ){

$uploads_dir = './soundupload/'.$username.'/';
if( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'], $uploads_dir
.$_FILES['Filedata']['name']  )
```

Comment: but you're using filereference upload? One problem with it is that you'll loose the session.

Comment: @redreggae. OK,thanks. I updeted the code. Now I send the username to php. It creates his folder but move files to soundupload folder not into his specific folder

Comment: it seems like `$_POST['sesname']` is empty? anyway..this is a big security risk, cause you can easily manipulate the POST values. Better to pass the session-id to flash and pass it back to PHP on upload. In PHP you can set the old session with `session_id($_POST['session_id_from_flash']);`. In this way you keep the old session. Another option is to use AMF for uploading.

Comment: I cannot verify it, but I think you'll only loose the session in firefox.